# Work around for EF6 bug 1748 in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework 6 fails to handle the maintenance of LocalDB's global list of databases. That is noted here: [Application fails when attached mdf and ldf files are deleted](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1748)

Here is my code to work around the issue. I'm open to suggestions to improve it.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Dapper;

namespace Asi.Server.History
{
    static class LocalDBUtilities
    {
        private static int _initializations;
        public static void InitializeDatabase(Database database)
        {
            if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _initializations, 1) == 0)
            {
                // if we have a filename specified but it doesn't exist, we should clear any existing databases that match that name
                // this a lame issue with LocalDB -- tracking all databases at a global level

                var connectionString = database.Connection.ConnectionString;
                if (connectionString.IndexOf("LocalDB", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    // attempt a quick check to make sure it's installed
                    ThrowIfNoLocalDBInstalled();

                    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
                    var filename = DbProviderServices.ExpandDataDirectory(builder.AttachDBFilename);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
                    {
                        var filesExist = File.Exists(filename);
                        if (!filesExist)
                            DropAndCreateLocalDatabase(filename, builder.InitialCatalog, builder);
                        else
                        {
                            // TODO: we need to ensure a matching entry in the master table
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    database.CreateIfNotExists();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // while(!Database.Exists()) Thread.Sleep(10); // not sure yet if this is needed and not sure how expensive the Exists call is
            }

        }

        private static void ThrowIfNoLocalDBInstalled()
        {
            var bad = new NotSupportedException("LocalDB is not installed.");
            using (var software = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"))
            {
                if (software == null) throw bad;
                using (var msft = software.OpenSubKey("Microsoft"))
                {
                    if (msft == null) throw bad;
                    using (var msldb = msft.OpenSubKey("Microsoft SQL Server Local DB"))
                    {
                        if (msldb == null) throw bad;
                        using (var ldbiv = msldb.OpenSubKey("Installed Versions"))
                        {
                            if (ldbiv == null || ldbiv.SubKeyCount <= 0) throw bad;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void DropAndCreateLocalDatabase(string filename, string database, SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.AttachDBFilename = "";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "";
            builder.ConnectTimeout = 5; // surely the DB engine can spin up in five seconds
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    connection.Execute("IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'" + database + "') DROP DATABASE [" + database + "]");
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    // expected partial completion exception
                }
                var logname = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "ldf");
                connection.Execute("CREATE DATABASE [" + database + "] ON PRIMARY (NAME = " + database + "_Dat, FILENAME = '" + filename.Replace("'", "''")
                    + "', SIZE = 3MB, MAXSIZE = 12GB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) LOG ON (NAME = " + database + "_Log, FILENAME = '" + logname.Replace("'", "''") + "')");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a little piece of code that can be shortened a little bit

```
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
       {
           var filesExist = File.Exists(filename);
           if (!filesExist)
               DropAndCreateLocalDatabase(filename, builder.InitialCatalog, builder);
           else
           {
               // TODO: we need to ensure a matching entry in the master table
           }
       }
```

if there is nothing inside that else statement you could code it like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) && !File.Exists(filename)) {
    DropAndCreateLocalDatabase(filename, builder.InitialCatalog, builder);
}
```

Otherwise you could write it still using the nested if statement

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename)) {
        DropAndCreateLocalDatabase(filename, builder.InitialCatalog, builder);
    } else {
        // TODO: we need to ensure a matching entry in the master table
    }
}
```

`filesExist` wasn't used again other than in that if statement so it really isn't needed, if it were used elsewhere within that scope then I would have left it as is.

---

I don't like the if statements throwing exceptions like this:

```
    private static void ThrowIfNoLocalDBInstalled()
    {
        var bad = new NotSupportedException("LocalDB is not installed.");
        using (var software = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"))
        {
            if (software == null) throw bad;
            using (var msft = software.OpenSubKey("Microsoft"))
            {
                if (msft == null) throw bad;
                using (var msldb = msft.OpenSubKey("Microsoft SQL Server Local DB"))
                {
                    if (msldb == null) throw bad;
                    using (var ldbiv = msldb.OpenSubKey("Installed Versions"))
                    {
                        if (ldbiv == null || ldbiv.SubKeyCount <= 0) throw bad;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so I don't like what I came up with either, but I think it is going to be better for what you are doing.

```
var bad = new NotSupportedException("LocalDB is not installed.");
var software = (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE") != null ? Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE") : throw bad);
using (software)
{
     var msft =  (software.OpenSubKey("Microsoft") != null ? software.OpenSubKey("Microsoft") : throw bad);
     using (msft)
     {
          var msldb = (msft.OpenSubKey("Microsoft SQL Server Local DB") != null ? msft.OpenSubKey("Microsoft SQL Server Local DB") : throw bad);
          using (msldb)
          {
              var ldbiv = (msldb.OpenSubKey("Installed Versions") != null || ldbiv.SubKeyCount > 0 ? msldb.OpenSubKey("Installed Versions") : throw bad);
          }
     }
 }
```

this way you throw the exception when assigning the variables rather than after already assigning them,  I think this is going to work better because of that fact.

it will probably run a little faster.